# Cookie Not Being Set in PHP

Tags: php, session-cookies, setcookie

There is a problem in setting the cookie in PHP.
This is the code that I am using to set a cookie if a checkbox is checked.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
    setcookie("loggedemail",$email,"time()+3600","/");
    setcookie("loggedpassword",$password,"time()+3600","/");
    echo $_COOKIE['loggedemail'];
    echo $_COOKIE['loggedpassword'];
}
?>
```

Here 'remember' is the id of the checkbox that I am using to set the cookies.
The issues here are

- I am not able to see the cookies on chrome's resources tab when I
  click "Inspect element".
- I am not able to see any echoes.
- The cookies are not being set.

Also, I am not able to delete the session cookie when a person logs out of the session.
`session_destroy();` does not seem to be doing the trick because Chrome still shows the cookie to be set active.

How do I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this:

```
setCookie("cookieName", "value", time() + 3600);
```

It has to work (if you didn't alter any browser settings). However, the variable isn't available till the next load of the page. You should be able to see it in Chrome dev tools though. If not, make 100% sure you're not outputting ANYTHING before you set the cookie.

Concerning your second problem, `session_destroy()` destroys a session, but it doesn't invalidate cookies already sent to the client. You need to manually invalidate them by setting their expiration time.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `$_COOKIE` is set by reading cookies received from the browser.

In order to receive a cookie from the browser it must be: set in PHP -> the browser should load -> the user should navigate to the next page (or submit a form).

So basically if you use `setcookie` you can't read `$_COOKIE` yet until the next refresh. That's why the `echo`s weren't showing anything. They were showing `NULL` - to confirm this use `var_dump` and you'll see the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing time as string. here is problem so change your php code as below

```
setcookie("loggedemail",$email,time()+3600,"/");
setcookie("loggedpassword",$password,time()+3600,"/");
```

Cookie are not part of session so you can't use session_destroy().

If you want to delete cookie, then you have to set time as past time as below

```
setcookie("loggedemail", "", time()-3600);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had set the name attribute as "remember" and not the id. My mistake. But still, I am not sure why the cookie is not being created.
I checked by passing the time as your code suggested. Any more ideas?

Comment: what you get in var_dump($_POST) ?? are you getting value of $email & $password ??

Answer (score 0):

`session_destroy()` does not unset the cookie with the session id in it,  it only trashes the session data.

You say the checkbox has the id attribute of 'remember' - does it have a name attribute? if not that is why everything is not working id's are not posted to the form action per HTML definition.